# Textarea rezise by dragging only horizontal

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Here is my code:

```
<%= Html.TextArea("txtMyTextArea", new { @style = "width: 100%; height:100%", @resize="horizontal" })%>
```

and it's not working. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished more easily using the `max-height` attribute and setting it equal to the `height`. See this [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/k55h7/).

You can also set a horizontal-constraint, by adding a `max-width` attribute. See this [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/k55h7/1/).

I believe in your code this would 'translate' as:

```
<%= Html.TextArea("txtMyTextArea", new { @style = "width: 200px; height: 200px; max-height: 200px;"})%>
```